# how to insert variable into a table in MySQL

Tags: java, jdbc, insert, prepared-statement

I know how to add data into a table. Like

```
String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO tablename (x_coord, y_coord)"
                            +"VALUES"
                            +"(11.1,12.1)";
s.execute(insertQuery);
```

11.1 and 12.1 can be inserted into table. Now given a float variable

```
float fv = 11.1;
```

how to insert fv into the table?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @eyazici I am using java

Comment: @wzb5210 Use prepared statements, see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JAVA, you can use prepared statements like this:

```
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

float floatValue1 = 11.1;
float floatValue2 = 12.1;

try {
    conn = getConnection();
    String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO tablename (x_coord, y_coord)"
                        +"VALUES"
                        +"(?, ?)";
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
    pstmt.setFloat(1, floatValue1);
    pstmt.setFloat(2, floatValue2);
    int rowCount = pstmt.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("rowCount=" + rowCount);
} finally {
    pstmt.close();
    conn.close();
}
```

Comment: @Emre Yazıcı By the way, I have a new question. How to insert an array as a string into the database. Like "11.1,12.1" is a string, but how to let "floatValue1,floatValue2" works?

Comment: @wzb5210 Why do you asking me? I am not the owner of the most suitable answer.

Comment: @Emre Yazıcı Oh, I am sorry, I just found the problem. I thought i could accept all correct answers. So I clicked your answer and then clicked another. I just realized that I could only accept one answer. Sorry for that.

Comment: @wzb5210 It does not matter. As for your question, please open a new question or update your question. Don't forget to give code example.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use a [Prepared Statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), as follows:

```
final PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO tablename (x_coord, y_coord) VALUES (?,?)");
stmt.setFloat(1, 11.1f);
stmt.setFloat(2, 12.1f);
stmt.execute();
```