# Passing a variable in MySQL statement

Tags: java, mysql, variables

I'm trying to record String variables into a database in a MySQL statement in Java.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566031/how-to-insert-variable-into-a-table-in-mysql) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573124/how-to-insert-variable-as-a-string-into-mysql-in-java) but I couldn't succeed.

Here is my code:

```
public void registerUser( String userName, String password ) {

    try {
        String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Credentials ('11', name, pass) VALUES('11', ?, ?)";
        pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
        pstmt.setString(2, userName);
        pstmt.setString(3, password);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
//          statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Credentials VALUES(3, 'userName', 'password')");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // close the connection when done
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }//END finally

}//END registerUser
```

As can you see, this code is getting two String values and it should put them into the database. But I can't find the proper solution.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: For me it's a clean solution. It's better that a series of string concatenations or anything else.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
pstmt.setString(2, userName);
pstmt.setString(3, password);
```

Needs to be:

```
pstmt.setString(1, userName);
pstmt.setString(2, password);
```

You are only setting two variables in your PreparedStatement, so you need to start counting at 1. The integers used in the *setter* methods need to match up with the question marks in your statement, not the parameter list of the given SQL string.

Comment: Changed it as you've said. But this time I'm getting an SQL syntax error for the String assignment saying that my syntax is wrong I should change it. What's wrong with it?

Comment: I think that error refers to the `'11'` you have for the column name.

Comment: Changed it to this: String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Credentials (11, name, pass) VALUES('11', ?, ?)";  Then this: String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Credentials VALUES('11', ?, ?)"; But with no luck. How that line should be exactly?

Comment: Is `11` really the column name? What is the name of the first column?

Comment: 11 stands for the user ID. Normally that value should be auto incremented but for now I'm changing it just to find the proper syntax for registering a user.

Comment: Your query should have the 11 in the VALUES parameter list, whereas the column name needs to be in the other parameter list... `INSERT INTO Credentials (USER_ID_COLUMN_NAME, name, pass) VALUES('11', ?, ?)`

Comment: Changed as you've said. Now it's not recognizing the column name but it's the correct one.